# Server error while trying to display data from mysql db in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database, db_db which I want to display data from in my browser. I have put this php code (display.php) under /var/www/ and trying to access `localhost/display.php`. Though everytime I come across "Server Error" The website encountered an error while retrieving `http://localhost/display.php`. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

The code is below:

```
<?php
 //make conn
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

 //select db
 mysql_select_db('db_db') or die( "Unable to select db");
 $sql =  "SELECT * FROM results WHERE jobid = 'abc'";
 $records = mysql_query($sql);
?>


<html>
<head>
 <title> Result Info </title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="600" border = "1" cellpadding = "1" cellspacing= "1">
<tr>
 <th>id</th>
 <th>name</th>
<tr>

<?php
 while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>.$result['id'].</td>";
   echo "<td>.$result['name'].</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }//end while
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure where am I going wrong.

Comment: This sounds more like an apache issue. Can you retrieve a simple html page?

Comment: Yes I have a info.php (phpinfo() ) in the same path i.e. /var/www/ which returns me the value as expected on `localhost/info.php`

Comment: the mysql_* functions are deprecated. You should look into using PDO or mysqli.  I also see an error in the code that generates the table cells.  `echo "<td>.$result['id'].</td>";` should be `echo "<td>" . $result['id'] . "</td>";`

Comment: This clearly doesn't seem to be programming related problem.

Comment: @Robbert: I think this might be something to do with the web server. I've also made sure that the apache has root privileges.

Comment: @learning, The most dangerous thing in Web Environment to web server have root level privileges. Also this not solve any problem at all.

Comment: For debug first check apache error logs, Their should be any information about error.

Comment: @Kuldeep: the apache access log says:
GET /display.php HTTP/1.1" 500 275 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22.

ANy idea what does that mean?

Comment: @learning, These are access logs, They only gave information about request. Their would be also error logs which would have error information. On Ubuntu their path should be /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: @Kuldeep: Checked the error message and figured the problem out.There was a small syntax error in the actual code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There might be the problem with your database select and query syntax.
Modify your code

```
<?php
 //make conn
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

 //select db
 mysql_select_db('db_db', $link) or die( "Unable to select db");
 $sql =  "SELECT * FROM results WHERE jobid = 'abc'";
 records = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Check if it works. Good luck

Comment: How is this different from above code? apart from assigning a variable to mysql_connect

Comment: its not just assigning the variable, Check the sixth line. It sets the current active database on the server that's associated with the specified link identifier. Please check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php